# Facebook graph api unable to get some properties like admin_notes, labels or custom_labels in comments listing

Tags: facebook

We are building an app that manage Facebook comments for page admins. When managing the comments, we want to know if there is any "admin_notes" or "custom_labels" that the page admin has previously applied on that specific owner of the comment.

I imagine the API is something like this:
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/45013343238491111/comments?order=reverse_chronological&fields=message,from{name,id,custom_labels,admin_notes,likes}&access_token=...

The api above should theoretically return list of comments made on a post, with their owners name, id, and custom_labels etc.

But the comment listing response is like this:

```
    {
   "data": [
      {
         "message": "sdfsdfsdf",
         "from": {
            "name": "Dora Chan",
            "id": "23424292416969420",
            "likes": {
               "data": [
                  {
                     "name": "Page name",
                     "id": "XXXXXX",
                     "created_time": "2019-05-29T06:03:42+0000"
                  }
               ],
               "paging": {
                  "cursors": {
                     "before": "Mzg5OTgwNzQ4MjcxNzU3",
                     "after": "Mzg5OTgwNzQ4MjcxNzU3"
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         "id": "450133432384921_450162525715345"
      },
      {....
```

Information like "page likes" is available. But information like admin_notes and custom_labels are not available.

Why is that so?

Note: 
I am using page access Token. All page related permissions are granted:
manage_pages, pages_show_list, publish_pages, pages_messaging, public_profile

If I call graph API on that specific user directly, i.e. https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/[userid]?fields=name,id,likes,custom_labels&access_token=...

The outcome is same, I can see only name, userid, likes, but I cannot see custom_labels

Comment: What type of access token are you using? What permissions were granted? Can you get those fields if you request them directly from the user object (using the user id)?

Comment: Added note with answer to your question

Comment: Which role/capabilities does the user that generated the page access token, have on the page?

Comment: The user generated the page access token is the page admin on that page

Comment: And is your app live, or are you still in dev mode? Facebook has gotten way more restrictive with giving out user details for apps in dev mode. Maybe try this with a user account that has a role in the app first - let them make a comment, have the admin add a note/custom label to that account … and then see if you get more data.

Comment: If all that doesn’t help either, maybe file a bug report and ask them under which conditions these fields are supposed to be available. https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs

Comment: App is live, The user making the comment is also a page admin. I will file bug thanks